# WPF - Handling a RoutedEvent in the parent for a specific control instance

Tags: wpf, routedevents

In my user control I have several textboxes e.g. Textbox1, Textbox2.

In the parent I only want to handle KeyDown events raised from Textbox1, not all Textbox

I have added a handler in the parent

```
this.AddHandler(TextBox.KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnTextboxGoToPageKeyDown));
```

but of course this will handle all KeyDown events which I don't want.

Do I have to add some conditional logic in the RoutedEventHandler to check where the event was raised from?

or is there a better way?

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just subscribe to TextBox1.KeyDown?

Comment: The AddHandler method only accepts the class not the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RoutedEventArgs` in your `OnTextboxGoToPageKeyDown` has a property named `Source` which have a references to the Object who raised the event. You can ask for that property when you need to execute your logic.

HTH

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Except it's the OriginalSource property not Source.